# How to make inline text with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: css

I have a `li` with a `span` that contains a text, and below I have some `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Problem, the html data goes below the first span. I want it to stay on the same line.

I also add that if the text is short, it works. If it is long, it goes on line below

**Goal** : "Informations : my informations"

**Current** : "Informations :
my informations"

I use `TailwindCSS`

I tried to use `flex flex-wrap on container but still have same problem`

How to solve this ?

My code :

```
<li className='flex flex-wrap'>
     <span className='font-semibold'>Eléments complémentaires :</span>
     <span className='break-words'
           dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html:"My test HTML without any tags",
           }}
      />
</li>
```

Comment: In the DOM explorer, what resulting HTML does this produce?  Are you indicating that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` isn't setting this content *within* the `<span>` but *outside* of it?

Comment: @David Hello. The DOM shows two spans. Both are correct. The text displays on line below only when the text is longer then the width of the card where the text is display

Comment: In that case are you asking about `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` or React at all?  Or are you asking about a styling issue with the resulting HTML and CSS?  The question keeps referencing `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but it sounds like that functionality is working as expected.  Can you edit the question to clarify the actual problem?

Comment: @David you are right, it was a CSS only problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks correct, Perhaps you will be getting the spacing issue either on resize of your window (since you have `flex-wrap:wrap` or your container width is fixed and the text moves to new line.

Check if `white-space: nowrap;` can be a quick solution in this case.
Set it on `break-words` class.

```
.break-words {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, quick fix. Thank you !